# API Gateway endpoint returning 200 along with an error

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

The following call goes through and the third party service integrated into the lambda works as expected, but the call returns an error along with a 200.

For your reference, we use Plaid to handle our financial transactions.

[Any idea on what's causing this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wUra.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

API gateway, when coupled to a Lambda - **always** returns status 200 by default if the Lambda successfully responded. **And note: This does not mean the lambda was *successful* just that it properly sent a response and an exception did not get raised above the lambda handler**

The status 200 is basically:

*Api* Hey. Lambda. Here is a request.

*Lambda* Cool. Ooooh. I messed up. But Im telling you about it with a return!

*Api* Cool, cool. You responded. Status 200

If you want other status you have to make use of Method and Integration Response templates, mappings.

If you have just a lambda integration (not a proxy!) on the back end between the Api and Lambda, then you should be able to just use some mapping: for example (python, and probably not that efficient, this is old code):

```
body_only_response_template = {
        "application/json": '''$input.path('$.body')\n'''
                            '''#if($input.path('$.statusCode').toString().contains("502"))\n'''
                            '''    #set($context.responseOverride.status = 502)\n'''
                            '''#end\n'''
                            '''#if($input.path('$.statusCode').toString().contains("400"))\n'''
                            '''    #set($context.responseOverride.status = 400)\n'''
                            '''#end'''
    }

lambda_successful_integration = apigateway.IntegrationResponse(
        status_code="200",
        content_handling=apigateway.ContentHandling.CONVERT_TO_TEXT,
        response_templates=body_only_response_template)

four_hundred_integration = apigateway.IntegrationResponse(
        status_code="400",
        content_handling=apigateway.ContentHandling.CONVERT_TO_TEXT,
        response_templates=body_only_response_template,
        selection_pattern='''.*"statusCode":.*4.*''')

five_hundred_integration = apigateway.IntegrationResponse(
        status_code="502",
        content_handling=apigateway.ContentHandling.CONVERT_TO_TEXT,
        response_templates=body_only_response_template,
        selection_pattern='''.*"statusCode":.*5.*''')
```

the above CDK python code is expecting the lambda to return a json object like so:

```
return {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": "json like object stringified"
```

}

---

however, if the API Gateway -> Lambda is set as "Lambda Proxy" then the only way to do this actually having the lambda raise an Exception past the handler, and letting the Lambda backend generate the response to ApiGateway.

Normally this will just result in a `502: Internal Service Error` response from ApiGateway, but again - using method response and integration response mapping - you can set it directly.  (do note the code I pulled this from is an XML response, which probably wont apply - but you can see the general idea)

```
error_template = {
            "text/xml": '''#set ($errorMessageObj = $util.parseJson($input.path('$.errorMessage')))\n'''
                        '''$errorMessageObj.message'''
        }

500_integation = apigateway.IntegrationResponse(
            status_code="500",
            content_handling=apigateway.ContentHandling.CONVERT_TO_TEXT,
            response_templates=error_template,
            selection_pattern='''.*500.*'''  # NOTE: Lambda integrations search against "errorMessage" with this regex
        )
```

the above mapping is expecting the lambda to throw an exception:

```
except Exception as e:
     raise SomethingWentWrong(json.dumps({
            "errorType": "InternalServiceError",
            "httpStatus": 500,
            "message": "Your message, again stringified if a json-like object!"
        }))
```

which causes the aws Lambda service backend to send a response to the api gateway that looks (something - its been a bit and im a bit hazy) like this:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "{\"errorType\": \"InternalServiceError\", \"httpStatus\": 500,\"message\": \"your Message here\"  }"
}
```

notice the actual error message is stringified when it reaches the API.

---

you can get more information about mappings here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html

**But TL:DR** -> Api Gateway with a Lambda defaults to 200 response if the lambda successfully returns, only showing another status code if you specifically map it - and with Proxy Integrations, only if the lambda raised an exception

It is entirely based on the resource connection between API Gateway and its services + the mappings that generate this response.